# How to setup Julia in VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia

I'm coming from a pure Windows Visual Studio programming background with little Linux experience. It seems possible to use [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) to program in Julia, but I can't figure out how to get things set up correctly.

Does anybody have good example `launch.json`, `tasks.json`, or other files that can serve as an example to build from?

This would be a great thing to see in a detailed tutorial.

Comment: Unfortunately after 5 years still not a clear answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is how things work if you are using the Julia extension for VisualStudio Code.

The extension adds a bunch of new commands. They all start with "julia", so filtering by that string should show you everything you can do with the extension.

In terms of running Julia code, the extension offers only two options right now. First, you can execute a command to start a REPL. This will just show a default Julia prompt, and you can interact with it like you would with any other Julia REPL. The second is that there is also a command, triggered by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, to send either the current editor selection or the current editor line to this REPL.

There is currently no further integration offered by the Julia extension. We do plan to add debugger support in the future, at which point I would expect <kbd>F5</kbd> to start the current file in the debugger, or something like that. But that functionality is probably a couple of months away.

Comment: Are debugging and breakpoints available now in VS Code for Julia?