# Can somebody help me make Visual Studio Code with Julia ?

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia

I am studying economics so I have not much experience in programming. I really would like to make Julia work on Visual Studio Code but I've been unsuccessful.
So I downloaded the Julia extension but I don't know how to define the settings. Do I need to create a launch.json file or any other file to make it work?
I think that somebody asked a similar question previously at "[How to setup Julia in VS code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40922302/how-to-setup-julia-in-vs-code?answertab=active#tab-top)" 
but the answer didn't really help me.

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: I'm afraid this type of question doesn't typically do very well on Stack Overflow, which is  focused on very specific technical questions & answers rather than "walk me through this" type requests. (There's nothing wrong with those; they just don't tend to work well here.) Perhaps there is a forum or chat room that can be of better assistance

Comment: Please try the Julia discourse forum. There's a specific [VS Code section](https://discourse.julialang.org/c/tools/vscode) where you're likely to find helpful pointers.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to install Julia on your Mac by downloading the julia dmg file from [here.](https://julialang.org/downloads/)  This puts an application in the Applications folder.

There are several ways to set things up so julia will run from command line. I used the following: 
 ln -fs "/Applications/Julia-0.6.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia" /usr/local/bin/julia

This should work if the name of your application, that you just installed, is julia-0.6.app

After running the above command, you should be able to type Julia on the command line and have it to start.

You can now create a Julia script and place it in the directory you're running from. I created a file named julia_test001.jl  It contained the following:

```
for i in 1:5
   print(i, ", ")
end
```

This is a very short Julia script I wrote for testing.

Now start VScode and install the Julia language support extension.  After that has loaded, open the file Julia_test001.jl. Once this file is opened, click the triangle in the upper right corner or open the command palette and select the option: run code. The julia_test001.jl should run and print the result 1,2,3,4,5.